# Dynamic dahsboard style screen

Tags: android, android-layout

The screen will have the items in "dashboard" style but will be dynamically set. Imagine that at the start of the app you check how many items you need to shown and you set that amount in your dashboard screen. So, for example, for two items will be look like

[image: 2 items layout]

for three maybe something like this

[image]

and for six something like this

[image]

I have some liberty here, for example if two items is better to show horizontal is ok, or the same goes for the three items (last one only fill the same size as the first one).

This screens are based on some "manual" test with LinearLayout's and seems to be doable. But before start to code this monster I want to know if there is any other viable options for this, based on maybe a Grid or RecycleView, or maybe third party library (I couldn't found any).

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **RecyclerView** in which you can **change LayoutManager dynamically.**
For example, when there are 2,3 items, you set LinearLayoutManager for your RecyclerView. In other case, you set GridLayoutManger for it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It took me more time than expected but finally get it working. Maybe I could try to do the same with LinearLayouts to see if is easier than RecyclerView, but for now it works.

Comment: What is your solution? Do you use RecyclerView with dynamic LayoutManager?

Comment: Yep, basically the RecyclerView with customs LayoutManagers, but basically what you said.

Comment: Ok. Glad that it helps